# Magento - Add Custom Logic on product_addtocart_form for Marketplace

Tags: php, forms, magento, marketplace

I'm creating a Marketplace logic for my webSite but I'm facing a problem with `product_addtocart_form` form.

I've customized the product page and I'm trying to set a customAttribute and retrieve it on the cart.

Example: The user has 3 options to select on the product page. I want to store the information of which option the user picked and retrieve it on the cart.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setData('marketplace_info', $customInfo);
```

The logic above works and I'm able to get it on the cart. The problem now is that I don't know how to set this information only after the user choose/submit the form.

The form that I'm trying to customize is placed on the `view.phtml` and the HTML is:

```
<form action="*magento-url*" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
```

Logic that I want to create:

User select one option (button) > My custom logic set a customAttribute (logic mentioned above) > Magento default logic add product to the cart.

Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way.Add a **input tag inside your form**. Add your value under the value part of input tag. Like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="newVal" value="<?php echo 'yourValue'?>">
```

Now in your **cart controller** you will easily get this value. And there you can **set the value in your session** or where ever you want. Dont forget to add a check "`if(isset('yourvalue')){}`" like this in your controller.

Comment: Hi Kingshuk. Thx for your answer. I've 2 questions: The user can choose between many options, so how I'll create the `input` tag after the user pick an option? And the `cart controller` you are referring to the `Cart.php`? If yes, I've to edit the `addProduct` function?

Comment: If its already a select field then you dont have to use input field ..because you will get that value in your cartController.php file

Comment: Nice Kingshuk. Thx for your help. I found the `CartController.php` and I'm making some changes on the file. Just to confirm, the function that I need to customize is the `function addAction`, right?

Comment: Exactly. But dont forget to override the controller. You dont want to edit magento core files. DO YOU !!!!!! BEWARE !!!!!